# Sending JSON text from Browser to JSF Managed Bean (Primefaces)

Tags: jquery, json, jsf, primefaces

I am working on a app where I am thinking of sending information back to the browser in JSON format and have java script render the page based on the information. In the same fashion, I want to push updates from the browser to the managed bean in JSON format. Can we accomplish this in JSF + Primefaces?

The reason we are thinking of using JSON is to limit the amount of data being passed back and forth.

Comment: JSF implementations and libraries incorporate their own Ajax mechanisms. The usual documentation does not specify internal details. I don't think adding in the mix your own JSON routines would be a good idea.

Comment: just place the json string in some string variable of your bean , than place it in your page in some h:inputHidden and access it from js (you can render/execute the h:inputHidden with f:ajax in order to bring from/to server the json string)

Comment: @Daniel i followed your comment and able to send the JSON data as string which appears in the http resonse with a backslash for each double quote. This makes dificult to parse from it. Can you suggest me how to parse the response data?

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend on using Gson [Gson User Guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

Here is a brief example of how create/send/parse json from server

in your bean do something like this

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
myJsonString = gson.toJson(someObjectOrListOfObjects);
```

in xhtml

```
<h:inputHidden id="my_json_data" value="#{myBean.someObjectOrListOfObjects}" />
```

in your js file

```
var data = $('input[id$="my_json_data"]').val();
data = jQuery.parseJSON(data); //to parse it, use dev tools/fire bug to add data variable to watch and observe it
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rolling your own JSF implementation that passes JSON instead of XML/HTML i'd suggest some other ways of minimizing the data being send.

**Make dialogs, tabviews, datatables, etc. dynamic.**

PrimeFaces has an option to make certain elements dynamic. This means they load on when the user requests these. This can boost page loads.

**Use smaller forms**

I see a lot of users that use but one `<h:form>` because if everything is in a form you can't forget to put a form around elements that require one. This is dead wrong and leads to posting everything in the form in stead of only relevant parts of the page. Use forms where they are needed and double check with something like firebug what is being sent.

**Use client side verification**

Use client side verification to prevent a user from sending wrong input. This way wrong data isn't being sent back and forth (for ever). A nice side-effect is that the user receives a quick 'response'. NOTE: this doesn't mean you can drop server side verification. Server side verification is needed for security purposes.

Comment: It's "instead" not "in stead" :). By the way, those are good advices but where's the JSON handling in your answer?

Comment: @Luiggi-Mendoza thanks for the "instead" correction. ;-) I advice the OP against the JSON idea. Instead I offer some alternatives to limit data traffic.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks for your response. They are all good inputs and I am looking at those stuff as well. I wanted to still know if there was a way to use the JSF framework but still pass JSON text.

Comment: @user1624890 if you want to send/retrieve JSON messages, follow Daniel's advice in his comment on your question.