# How to send json from primefaces to jquery

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsf-2, primefaces

I'd like to ask how send json from primefaces to jquery on frontend? I have simple json:

```
this.jsonObject.put("key", "value");
```

And i dont know even how to start sending and recive data.

Comment: general JSF2 approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12191485/617373

Comment: Yes i know but in these tutorial is send by button i want to send it automaticly after page reload

Answer (score 3):

Use [RequestContext](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html)'s addCallbackParam feature ([example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/requestContext.jsf)).